# Удалить значения массива

Tags: массивы, javascript, ajax, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет!

Хочу вот что уточнить
У меня есть ajax запрос выполняющейся каждые 5 сек:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/1.php",
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data){
            // Результатом выаолнения функции будет 3 одномерных массива login, la, lo
        },

        error: function(){
            alert('Проблема с загрузкой скрипта');
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Вопрос: можно ли перед очередным ajax запросом удалить данные в трех массивах?
Я понимаю что каждый раз ajax запрос формирует новый массив, но в результате этого у меня происходит наложение одного координат одной метки на другой( работаю с яндекс картой), как этого избежать? Я уверен здесь есть тривиальное решение, но никак не могу прозреть!

Код sucsess

```
success: function(data){
    //var a = data;
    var json ='[{"login":"370","la":"48.310736","lo":"38.043989"},{"login":"399","la":"48.313092","lo":"37.973239"},{"login":"140","la":"48.300127","lo":"38.017115"},{"login":"1209","la":"48.308369","lo":"38.021465"},{"login":"142","la":"48.308157","lo":"38.025267"},{"login":"122","la":"48.331019","lo":"38.105643"},{"login":"3129","la":"48.300707","lo":"38.020754"},{"login":"3138","la":"48.34084","lo":"37.972458"},{"login":"190","la":"48.334623","lo":"38.052168"}]';
    var a = [] ; 
    a = JSON.parse(json);

    for (var i=0;i<a.length;++i) {
        var login = a[i].login,
            la = a[i].la,
            lo =a[i].lo;
        var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
            // Координаты метки
            [la, lo],
            {iconContent:login},
            {preset: 'twirl#redStretchyIcon'},
            {draggable: true}
        );      
        // Добавление метки на карту
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    }
    console.log(data);
    //setInterval( myPlacemark = null , 5000 );
    //setInterval( la = 0, 500 );
    //setInterval( lo = 0, 500 );
    console.log(myPlacemark);
},
```

Comment: Наверное код success нужно будет приложить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. хранить массив принятных через ajax объектов, и каждый раз проверять вновь пришедшие на совпадение координат, или целиком. Рисовать метки только для действительно новых.

Вариант 2. каждый раз стирать все метки, и рисовать заново. Наверное, через [методы GeoObjects](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/map.GeoObjects.xml#methods-summary) `each()` и `remove()`

Comment: с помощью `myMap.geoObjects.remove(myCollection);` сразу перед установлением центра, как-то так:
`myMap.geoObjects.remove(myCollection);
myMap.balloon.close();
myMap.setCenter([координаты], 11); }`

Comment: Вариант 1. хранить массив принятных через ajax объектов, и каждый раз проверять вновь пришедшие на совпадение координат, или целиком. Рисовать метки только для действительно новых.
Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Товарищи уже битый час пытаюсь понять как решить свою задачу


Я написал вот такой вот метод 
setInterval(function() { myMap.geoObjects.remove(myPlacemark);}, 5000); 

Но он удаляет только последнюю метку

Подскажите как сохранить объекты моих меток в массив? И удалить метки в массиве командой myMap.geoObjects.remove(myPlacemark);

Comment: Попробуйте так:

` for (var i=0;i<a.length;++i) {
        var login = a[i].login,
            la = a[i].la,
            lo =a[i].lo;
        var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
            // Координаты метки
            [la, lo],
            {iconContent:login},
            {preset: 'twirl#redStretchyIcon'},
            {draggable: true}
        );      
        // Добавление метки на карту
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    }
myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);
myMap.setBounds(myCollection.getBounds());`

Comment: Вам в помощь: http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/vyvodim-soderzhimoe-csv-fajla-na-yandeks-kartu-versiya-dlya-api-2-x
Тут и добавление меток, и их удаление.

Comment: твой код не корректен! во первых я не объявлял коллекция и у меня нет переменной myCollection
во вторых
myMap.setBounds(myCollection.getBounds()); - выставляет центр карты с максимальным приближением к объекту
в третьих 
у меня инициализирован метод setInterval, который будет создавать  каждый раз новую метку не удаляя старую, вот с этим я и пытаюсь бороться